# PostgreSQL TIMEZONE configuration

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm having the following problem:

I need to configure the TIMEZONE of my PostgreSQL installation, because from different terminals I'm obtaining different results when converting timestamps to dates.

I have read that the command to change the time zone is: `SET TIMEZONE = 'xxx'`.

However, from one terminal I can set the parameter without problems, but from the production server, whenever I set the timezone and I query with SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE'); I obtain UTC (which is not the time zone I'm setting it to).
It seems to not follow the command and keep the value it has already configured.

Any reason why such a behaviour could be occurring? Am I operation under some false assumption?

Comment: SET works on database connection level. Every connection can have it's own setting. But you could also set a default in the database configuration. ALTER DATABASE ... SET ...; or set the configuration for the entire database server in postgresql.conf

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong, like querying from different connections. The `SET` command changes the setting only for the current database session. Perhaps you are using a connection pool, then you will have to set the parameter every time you get a connection from the pool.

Comment: I am using the same user/password from different clients. When I execute:
SELECT current_setting('timezone');
I obtain localtime from my computer, and UTC from the production server.

Comment: Even if you do `BEGIN; SET timezone = 'Europe/Vienna'; SHOW timezone; COMMIT;`?